# Was there a non-parasite killed in Total Rickall?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In Rick and Morty season 2 episode 4 (Total Rickall), the protagonists have to kill a bunch of shapeshifting parasites that implant false memories in the victims and then take the form of the person that the memories describe. When a parasite dies, it immediately shifts back to its original, parasitic form. However, in a short clip from the episode, one creature doesn't shift back. Does anyone know who he is and why he might be important?

[image]

And here's the clip that I found it from, starting at the appropriate time:

EDIT: He's been identified as the Amish Cyborg by a commenter. But the thing that confuses me is how he doesn't shift when he's killed. The parasites usually shift before they even hit the ground, but it's as if the show creators purposefully drew out the scene so the audience could realize he wasn't shapeshifting. The scene changed a moment after he had hit the ground, with no evidence of changing into a parasite when he should've been mid-transformation by that point.

Comment: It cuts away pretty abruptly, though. Maybe he didn't just morph right away. [Look how long it took uncle Steve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbVvF5wWqf0).

Comment: "Who he is" is Amish Cyborg.  http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Amish_Cyborg

Comment: Amish Cyborg's blood is purple, and his eyes are starting to bulge. (If you notice, when Mr. Poopy Butthole is shot, his blood is red.) I think he's a parasite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely a parasite.
Originally the left side of his face had two cybernetic eyes.
When he hits the floor he has two regular bulging eyes and a one cybernetic eye above his once cybernetic eye.

Answer (score 2):

It took Uncle Steve a while to turn back! Maybe the creators just wanted to emphasise how many parasites were there and 'Amish Cyborg' didn't really get any screen time until then.

Good catch though!